# Using \xdef in \foreach errors when using another \foreach inside the \xdef

Tags: foreach

I'm using TeXShop 5.0.4 and encountering a cryptic error

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 15.
<inserted text>
               \fi
```

where my code contains no explicit "if"s.

How can I create a loop that defines various commands, each of which contains its own loop?

Explanations and solutions greatly appreciated.

Small repro:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% given input x, define \allx as a function that consumes input list qlist and operates on the elements of qlist (here, prints "x: q", but eventually some tikz command)
% This errors out with the comprehensive error
% ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 15.
% <inserted text>
%                \fi
\newcommand{\allcolor}[1]{\expandafter\xdef\csname all#1\endcsname##1{\foreach \q in {##1} {#1: \q}}}
% Interestingly, the \foreach seems to cause the error. If using the command below instead, which just prints "x: qlist", LaTeX is happy.
%\newcommand{\allcolor}[1]{\expandafter\xdef\csname all#1\endcsname##1{#1: ##1}}

% Reasons for pieces of the above code:
% use \xdef instead of edef to make the new function global, since \allcolor will be called in a loop, from with edef would only define the function within the loop body
% use \xdef instead of \newcommand because of other cryptic errors with \newcommand
% use \expandafter on \xdef since we first need to form the name of the new function, "\all#1", via \csname

% given input list {x,y,z}, call \allcolor on each one, to define \allx \ally and \allz
\newcommand{\allcolors}[1]{\foreach \color in {#1} {\allcolor{\color}}}

\allcolors{orange}

\begin{document}
\allorange{ha,haa}
\end{document}
```

Edit: the eventual goal is to define \allorange, \allbrown, (with the ability to easily add other color commands), that each process a list of coordinate pairs, and plot points of that color within tikz.

Using `egreg`'s answer, I was able to do so, with the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\edef\getxnow(#1,#2){#1}
\edef\getynow(#1,#2){#2}
\newcommand*{\getx}[1]{\expandafter\getxnow#1}
\newcommand*{\gety}[1]{\expandafter\getynow#1}

\newcommand{\allcolor}[1]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname all#1\endcsname##1{%
    \foreach \pt in {##1} {\node at (\getx{\pt}, \gety{\pt})[circle, fill, inner sep=5pt, #1]{};}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\allcolors}[1]{\foreach \r in {#1} {\expandafter\allcolor\expandafter{\r}}}

% Define \allorange and \allbrown which create points of those colors
\allcolors{orange, brown}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} {
\allorange{(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)}
\allbrown{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}
} \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Notes for commenters:

- In the original code, I did not think anything of my local loop variable name `\color` - it was an arbitrary name, and any other name will do
- It seems that `\xdef` tends to break stuff, while `\gdef` ends up working. I can see from [What are the differences between \def, \edef, \gdef and \xdef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353138/what-are-the-differences-between-def-edef-gdef-and-xdef) that `\xdef = \global\edef` expands replacement text at definition time, while `gdef = \global\def` doesn't. I'm not familiar of the inner workings of TeX replacement, so an explanation of why one succeeds while the other fails would help casual users' understanding.

Resources consulted:

- [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand)
- [What are the differences between \def, \edef, \gdef and \xdef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353138/what-are-the-differences-between-def-edef-gdef-and-xdef)
- [Undefined control sequence when using \edef with \foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516003/undefined-control-sequence-when-using-edef-with-foreach?newreg=34e3aca1802f4530b7483b8cd420ce47)
- https://tikz.dev/pgffor
- [Alternative to `foreach` loop to use an `edef`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308014/alternative-to-foreach-loop-to-use-an-edef)

  - this comes the closest to some answer, but the solution posted there is for that specific question, and didn't have enough explanation for me to understand how to use `expl3` for any other use case
- [Defining new commands inside a for loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57036/defining-new-commands-inside-a-for-loop)
- [\foreach with \newcommand how to use them together?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207985/foreach-with-newcommand-how-to-use-them-together)

Comment: most latex constructs will fail in an xdef, certainly `\foreach` does assignments so can not possibly work.

Comment: also `\foreach \color` will over-write the standard `\color` command, Can you say in words what you want `\allcolors{orange}` and `\allorange{ha,haa}` to do?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but as long as the standard `\color` is not needed inside the `\foreach`-code it'll not hurt because of the implicit groups. Though it is still a bad idea.

Comment: It seems like you want to use `\gdef` instead of `\xdef`.

Comment: @Skillmon sure but i couldn't guess what this code was intended to do.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the comments - please see the updated "Notes for commenters" in the question.

In short:  
* `\color` was an arbitrary loop variable name - I'll change to something else
* Overall goal description (and working code, now!) added to the Question
* If possible, an explanation of why `\foreach` inside `\xdef` won't work (but does work within `\gdef`) would be useful

Comment: @Skillmon thanks for the comments - see my reply to DavidCarlisle above

Comment: You might want to read [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668) ■ [macros - What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands? When and why do we need \protect? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736) ■ [verbatim - Why can't I use <some macro> inside the argument of <some other macro>? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645995) (disclaimer, last one is my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what your macros are supposed to achieve, but the main problem is that `\foreach` cannot be used in `\xdef`.

With the following code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\allcolor}[1]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname all#1\endcsname##1{%
    \foreach \q in {##1} {#1: \q\par}%
  }%
}

% given input list {x,y,z}, call \allcolor on each one, to define \allx \ally and \allz
\newcommand{\allcolors}[1]{\foreach \r in {#1} {\expandafter\allcolor\expandafter{\r}}}

\allcolors{orange}

\begin{document}

\allorange{ha,haa}

\end{document}
```

(added `\par` for clarity of output) I get

[image]

The command `\allorange` has replacement text

```
\foreach \q in {#1} {orange: \q \par }
```

Comment: This worked, and I updated the Question with a working version of my eventual goal based on this. Thanks!

Comment: Technically you could do like `\protect\foreach` or `\noexpand\foreach`, but indeed `\gdef` is easier in this case.

Comment: @user202729 the `\protect` mechanism will not work in a normal `\xdef`, if you want to use that mechanism one has to use `\protected@xdef` instead.

Comment: @egreg Why are the `\expandafter` calls within the `\allcolors` definition necessary?

@user202729 and @Skillmon can you explain how + why `\protect` or `\protected@xdef` would help here?

Comment: Found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345899/how-does-expandafter-interact-with : `\expandafter` operates on the `{` token, so
`\newcommand{\allcolors}[1]{\foreach \r in {#1} {\expandafter\allcolor\expandafter{\r}}}` `\allcolors{x,y}` expands the token following `\allcolor` before it, which is another `expandafter`:
expanding the `\r` to each loop iteration before the `{` expands (to itself), then finally evaluating `allcolor{x}` and `allcolor{y}` (including the necessary curly braces).

Nested macros + expansion timing are quite counter-intuitive for C/C++ programmers...